# Swift& Parse.com Adding values from a table into an array error not having a member named subscript

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I have a table called Assesment 
[image: table]

it has the *name* and *send* values of each task 
what I needed to do is to retrieve all these tasks and store them in an array

and here is my code which gives me an error saying that PFObject doesn't have a member called send:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()


//test


        var taskQuery = PFQuery(className: "Assesment")

        //run query
        taskQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
            (success:[AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if (success != nil) {

                for object:PFObject! in success as! [PFObject]{
             ERROR>>>>       taskMgr.addtask(object.name,send: object.name)
                }

                println(taskMgr)

            }})

        //test



        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
```

even thought I tried to say instead

taskMgr.addtask(object)

AssesmentManager.swift class:

```
import UIKit

var taskMgr : AssesmentsManager = AssesmentsManager()

struct task {
    var name = "Un-Named"

    var send = false
}

class AssesmentsManager: NSObject {

    var tasks = [task]()

    func addtask(name: String, send: Bool) {

        tasks.append(task(name: name,  send: send))

    }


}
```

**UPDATE**

```
 if (success != nil) {

        for object:PFObject! in success as! [PFObject]{
            if object["send"]=="true"{
                 taskMgr.addtask(object["name"], true )
            }

            else{
                taskMgr.addtask(object["name"], false )}
        }
```

I updated it to remove the string, boolean problem but I still have the same error of not having a member named subscript

**UPDATE#2**

This is what it looks like now, but still giving me an error that objects is unresolved:

```
 var taskQuery = PFQuery(className: "Assesment")

        //run query
        taskQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
            (success:[AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if (success != nil) {

                for object:PFObject! in success as! [PFObject]{
           for object in objects  {
                        taskMgr.addtask(object["name"], (object["send"] == "true"))
                    }



                }

                println(taskMgr)

            }})
```

Comment: updated to taskMgr.addtask(object["name"], send: object["send"]) but it still give me an error says that PFObject doesn't have a member named subscript

Comment: you're passing a string to a bool parameter. send is defined as bool in your function but object["name"] is a string

Comment: is casting a good ides, or should I change send in AssesmentManager class and make string?

Comment: what value do you intend to represent with the 'send' parameter?

Comment: I updated my question. I pasted at the end of the question my edit on the code but still the error appears

Comment: it's supposed to be either true or false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift 2.0, findObjects returns optional array of PFObject instead of optional AnyObject. Try this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var taskQuery = PFQuery(className: "Assesment")

    taskQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success:[PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if let objects = success {
            for object in objects {
                taskMgr.addtask(object["name"], (object["send"] == "true"))
                //taskMgr.addtask(object["name"], (object["send"].isEqual("true")))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in the line **for object in objects {** it says use of unresolved identifier **objects**

Comment: i tried even casting it but it still gives me the error, my xcode is 6.4

Comment: is there any way to loop through the table instead of for object in objects { since it's giving me an error?

Comment: now it gives an error on **object["send"] == "true")** saying *couldn't find an overload for "==" that accepts the supplied arguements*

Comment: Oh man, I just saw that your Xcode is 6.4. the above code is for Xcode 7.0 and swift 2
I think you need to use isEqualto NSString method in that case. or simply upgrade

Comment: I changed it into **taskMgr.addtask(object["name"], send: true)** to check if it'll work but it said *cannot invoke addTask with an arguement list of type (AnyOject?!, send: Bool)*

Comment: and when I changed it into **askMgr.addtask("added", send: true)** it worked, I can't understand where the error is coming from

Comment: I changed it into *taskMgr.addtask(object["name"], (object["send"].isEqual("true"))) * but it says that the value of anyObject is unwrapped on the second part: **send"].isEqual("true"))**

Comment: I just tried           println(object["name"]) to see what value it gives, and it actually printed "Optional(the tasks's name" I don't know why because i only was calling "name"

Comment: well, then safely unwrap it to string. I suggest you upgrade to swift 2.0 though

Comment: Thank you very much, my function is working after unwrapping the string